# Loggin into Portal / WAS by PKI certificate

Tags: authentication, websphere-portal, pki, digital-certificate

We are developing a portal for a client using IBM websphere portal v8.5, the client employees have digital certificates on their computers. the client requires to use these certificates to authenticate against WAS security, replacing the need to input username and password when a user wants to log into portal?
Do you have any idea from where i can start, is there any way to do this in IBM portal?

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere Portal bases on top of the general security functions of WebSphere Application server. There are some extensions Portal provides in addition, but for certificate verification this is handled by the general WebSphere infrastructure.

Below a startpoint. 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0508_benantar/0508_benantar.html